# Why does 'call()' add properties to the Function's instance?? (see small code)

Tags: javascript

Why is it that just by using `call` you're adding properties to the `Employee` instance named `jc`?

I'm wondering why `jc.hasOwnProperty('firstName');` results to `true`.

I didn't even do `prototype` inheritance yet. This is all the code, no more no less:

I understand that `call` just changes the `this` while passing in arguments, but to add properties? I don't know what's going on...

```
function Person(firstName, lastName){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
function Employee(firstName, lastName, position){
  Person.call(this,firstName,lastName);
  this.position = position;
}
var jc = new Employee('JC','Viray','Developer');
jc.hasOwnProperty('firstName'); //true
```

**UPDATE**

I get it now.. the solution to my problem is:
**stop thinking in C#/Java mentality**.. I lost track that `Person` is **still** a `FUNCTION` despite it being a "constructor type function"...  -_- once a function, still a function..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering why jc.hasOwnProperty('firstName'); results to true.

Because of this line in the `Person` function:

```
this.firstName = firstName;
```

When you say

```
Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);
```

You're actually **calling** the `Person` function, and telling `Person` to set **its** `this` value to what's provided in the first argument—in your case, the Employee object you're in the process of building.  The subsequent arguments to `call` then get passed along as regular parameters.

As a result, `Person` gets called with `this` set to be your current `Employee` object, and picks up a `firstName` and `lastName` property.

---

Or consider an alternate example.

```
var obj = { };
Person.call(obj, "Adam", "Rackis");
obj.hasOwnProperty('firstName'); //still true
```

Comment: yeah.. finally I actually get it now (just clicked)... I still had a 'class' mentality/paradigm and thinking of Person as a class in C#/Java sense... lost track that it's *still* a function..(!)

Comment: @JanCarloViray - exactly.  JavaScript is an incredibly tricky language to learn coming from C#, Java, etc.  Looks like you're well on your way though.

Comment: thank you :) that is definitely an encourage statement to hear :)

Comment: @JanCarloViray - when you start to get the hang of it, pick up Douglas Crockford's book JavaScript the good parts - it's incredible.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling

```
Person.call(this,firstName,lastName);
```

which means that the function `Person`, `this` refers to whatever `this` refers to in `Employee` (a new object). Inside `Person`, you are assigning values to `this.firstName` and `this.lastName`.

You could have written the same as:

```
function Employee(firstName, lastName, position){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.position = position;
}
```

> I understand that call just changes the this while passing in arguments, but to add properties?

`call` does not add properties to the object, but your function does. And that's exactly why it is used in this case. You want to apply everything inside `Person` to the new object as if you had called `new Person(a, b)`.

Comment: but I haven't really set up a connection between Employee & Person though through `prototype`? I know how `call` works, which you just described but to add properties to an Employee instance? Does `call` do that too??

Comment: I tried to explain it. You know what happens inside `Person`. You are setting `firstName` and `lastName` to `this`. You know that using `call`, a function gets executed with a specific value set for `this`. You are setting `this` inside `Person` to the same value as `this` inside `Employee`, hence they are the same. That's the connection. I don't see how it can be explained any better.

Comment: ohhhh. I get it now! took a bit of rereading but I get it now :) Thanks :) -- (i still had a 'class' mentality so I didn't 'see' Person is STILL a function)